# malformed config.xml phonegap build error

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

Please can anyone assist me on and how to correct why am receiving malformed config.xml
I have looked through and can't seem to find where the error is coming from.
Please any assistance will be appreciated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           id="com.mohammed.iradani"
           version="8"
    >
    <name short="IRADANI">
    IRADANI GH
    </name>
    <description>
    The Best App ever
    </description>
    <author email="xyz@gmail.com" href="http://iradani.com">
    Mohammed Bashiru
    </author>
    <icon src="img/icon256.png" width="256" height="256" />
    <icon src="img/icon48.png" width="48" height="48" />
    <icon src="img/icon32.png" width="32" height="32" />
    <icon src="img/icon24.png" width="24" height="24" />
    <icon src="img/icon16.png" width="16" height="16" />
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <gap:platform name="android"/>
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="android-MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    </widget>
```

Comment: Check log and please tell me where is error!